# Weird Chinese site when trying to access skeptics.stackexchange.com

Tags: support

I just tried to access skeptics.stackexchange.com and I landed on a page that looked like this:

[image: Have the Chinese taken over?!]

The site is back to normal but it was like this for a few minutes. Why is this? Was this my problem or a problem with the website?

`Chromium 12.0.742.91 (87961) Built on Ubuntu 11.04, running on LinuxMint 11`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make sure that you don't have any malware installed that redirects you to different websites. That is the most likely explanation, though it is possible that there was a temporary problem with the DNS entries for the site.

Comment: Hm I seem to get redirected to that website (in all browsers) whenever I go to a site that doesn't exist. I'm guessing there was a temporary DNS problem. Why I get redirected to that site is another question of it's own but that's not really suited to here.

Comment: I've now asked on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/49817/667).